# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error message

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

This is in SSMS

I am trying to insert the follow dummy test statements and its failing

```
INSERT INTO Client 
(
     [name], 
     [address], 
     [DOB], 
     [Mobile], 
     [Email], 
     [profession], 
     [refby]
)
VALUES 
(
     'Toby Keith', 
     '8 big dog daddy lane oklahoma 40518', 
     '28/06/2010', 
     '0424 280 185', 
     'tk@hotmail.com', 
     'Country Superstar', 
     'Willie'
)
```

The message i get is:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

now i have used this plenty of times without a problem what small little stupid thing am i missing?

Comment: Are you running the query with the same user as usual ? or have you changed your language settings ?

Comment: God im an idiot i hadn't set the date time format

and was using int for the mobile numbers instead of nvarchar!!

sorry folks for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISO` date-time format -

```
INSERT INTO Client 
(
     [name], 
     [address], 
     [DOB], 
     [Mobile], 
     [Email], 
     [profession], 
     [refby]
)
VALUES 
(
     'Toby Keith', 
     '8 big dog daddy lane oklahoma 40518', 
     '20100628', 
     '0424 280 185', 
     'tk@hotmail.com', 
     'Country Superstar', 
     'Willie'
)
```